# Getting .profile to execute after .bash_login

Tags: bash, unix

When I installed RVM, it turns out that it created .bash_login with this:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session as a function`

And I now have to manually source .profile, where my BASH configs are.  How do I get .profile to automatically execute?

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete `~/.bash_login`
2. Move `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session as a function` into the bottom of your `~/.profile`.
3. Success!

Comment: Thanks!  And shell session - what's the format for that?

Comment: Everything after the `#` is a comment, there is no specific format

Comment: Okay, so I just copy that line and paste into the bottom of the .profile file?  Sorry, I don't have experience setting up a function so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: That's correct. Just move the contents of `~/.bash_login` as-is into `~/.profile`, preferably at the bottom. Delete `~/.bash_login`. Done